# Facing a challenge with the "Fetch As Google" feature in my webmaster

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, fetch-as-google

I am facing a challenge with the "Fetch As Google" feature in my webmaster

Steps to reproduce bug:-
1. Goto webmaster , click on "Crawl" -> "Fetch As Google"
2. Select "Crawl this URL and its direct links" , select the captcha

Observation:-
An error is thrown "An error has occurred. Please try again later."

Impact - I am unable to ask google to crawl my pages

Some solution that i tried
a) Request indexing for HTTP version
b) Then request indexing for HTTPS version

This isn't working

Requst your advice guys.
Thanks in advance 
:)

Comment: How long has this been happening? I've gotten random Google errors before where tests didnt successfully complete but then the next day all was fine.

Comment: Yeah I would wait 24 hours and try again.